# Which KPI Library Is IODeviceMemory Declared In?

Tags: macos, driver, iokit, kernel-extension, xnu

Google yields no insight.  I wasn't able to figure it out by searching
around in the kernel source.

I'm using the open source IOProxyVideoFamily to implement a virtual framebuffer.

I just replaced a C-style cast to IODeviceMemory with OSDynamicCast,
because I suspect that cast will fail.  If so I will know how to fix
it.

But I can't find the KPI library that contains it.  IODeviceMemory has
been in the OS since 10.0, and is required for PCI card drivers.

```
$ kextlibs -undef-symbols /System/Library/Extensions/IOProxyFramebuffer.kext/

For all architectures:
   com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily = 2.4.1
   com.apple.kpi.iokit = 15.6
   com.apple.kpi.libkern = 15.6
   com.doequalsglory.driver.IOProxyVideoCard = 1.0d1

For x86_64:
   1 symbol not found in any library kext:
   ZN14IODeviceMemory9metaClassE
```

IODeviceMemory is a subclass of IOMemoryDescriptor.  It's declaration
includes OSDeclareDefaultStructors.

(The dependence on IOProxyVideoCard is satisfied when the video card
driver is installed.)

Answer (score 1):

`IODeviceMemory` is a weird `IOMemoryDescriptor` subclass in that it doesn't override any virtual functions and doesn't add any fields. So it's really just a few static helper functions for `IOMemoryDescriptor`. If you look at the source code for those helper functions, you'll find that **none of them actually create an instance of `IODeviceMemory`** - instead they call down to `IOSubMemoryDescriptor::withSubRange()` (which obviously creates an `IOSubMemoryDescriptor` object) and `IOMemoryDescriptor::withAddressRange()` (I believe this latter one creates an `IOGeneralMemoryDescriptor`).

So your dynamic cast wouldn't work anyway, `IODeviceMemory` doesn't really exist - there are normally no instances of it around. I suspect this is why the auto-generated OSMetaClass stuff for it isn't exported via a KPI.