# Making a virtual IOPCIDevice with IOKit

Tags: macos, emulation, iokit, pci, pci-e

I have managed to create a virtual IOPCIDevice which attaches to IOResources and basically does nothing. I'm able to get existing drivers to register and match to it.

However when it comes to IO handling, I have some trouble. IO access by functions (e.g. configRead, ioRead, configWrite, ioWrite) that are described in IOPCIDevice class can be handled by my own code. But drivers that use memory mapping and IODMACommand are the problem.

There seems to be two things that I need to manage: IODeviceMemory(described in the IOPCIDevice) and DMA transfer.

How could I create a IODeviceMemory that ultimately points to memory/RAM, so that when driver tries to communicate to PCI device, it ultimately does nothing or just moves the data to RAM, so my userspace client can handle this data and act as an emulated PCI device?

And then could DMA commands be directed also to my userspace client without interfering to existing drivers' source code that use IODMACommand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Trapping memory accesses**

So in theory, to achieve what you want, you would need to allocate a memory region, set its protection bits to read-only (or possibly neither read nor write if a read in the device you're simulating has side effects), and then trap any writes into your own handler function where you'd then simulate device register writes.

As far as I'm aware, you can do this sort of thing in macOS userspace, using Mach exception handling. You'd need to set things up that page protection fault exceptions from the process you're controlling get sent to a Mach port you control. In that port's message handler, you'd:

- check where the access was going to
- if it's the device memory, you'd suspend all the threads of the process
- switch the thread where the write is coming from to single-step, temporarily allow writes to the memory region
- resume the writer thread
- trap the single-step message. Your "device memory" now contains the written value.
- Perform your "device's" side effects.
- Turn off single-step in the writer thread.
- Resume all threads.

As I said, I believe this can be done in user space processes. It's not easy, and you can cobble together the Mach calls you need to use from various obscure examples across the web. I got something similar working once, but can't seem to find that code anymore, sorry.

**… in the kernel**

Now, the other problem is you're trying to do this in the kernel. I'm not aware of any public KPIs that let you do anything like what I've described above. You could start looking for hacks in the following places:

- You can quite easily make `IOMemoryDescriptor`s backed by system memory. Don't worry about the `IODeviceMemory` terminology: these are just `IOMemoryDescriptor` objects; [the `IODeviceMemory` class is a lie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46236088/48660). Trapping accesses is another matter entirely. In principle, you can find out what virtual memory mappings of a particular MD exist using the "reference" flag to the `createMappingInTask()` function, and then call the `redirect()` method on the returned `IOMemoryMap` with a `NULL` backing memory argument. Unfortunately, this will merely suspend any thread attempting to access the mapping. You don't get a callback when this happens.
- You could dig into the guts of the Mach VM memory subsystem, which mostly lives in the `osfmk/vm/` directory of the xnu source. Perhaps there's a way to set custom fault handlers for a VM region there. You're probably going to have to get dirty with private kernel APIs though.

**Why?**

Finally, why are you trying to do this? Take a step back: What is it you're ultimately trying to do with this? It doesn't seem like simulating a PCI device in this way is an end to itself, so is this really the only way to do what greater goal you're ultimately trying to achieve? [See: XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Hey pmdj, thanks for suggestions. I was also wondering how to get notified when driver has performed a write to the "device" memory.

However, can macOS point directly to PCIe device's memory space with IOMemoryDescriptor? By reading Apple's PCIe driver's source code it seems that they extensively use IODMACommand. Also by examining some of PCIe IC datasheets, it usually requires a trigger messaging by e.g. configWrite to tell the IC that a new message has been written in. But most importantly, do you think notification could be made via IODMACommand call?

Comment: @kpeteL The purpose of IODMACommand is mostly to make sure some system memory buffer's physical memory pages are wired down for the duration of the device's access to them (so they don't get moved by the kernel's VM system), and to obtain the corresponding physical (or IOMMU-space) address ranges. (AKA "scatter-gather list") How these scatter-gather lists are passed to the device is device-specific, but it's pretty much got to be written to a BAR (memory-mapped or I/O), to PCI config space, or to another DMA buffer whose location and size has previously been written to BAR or config.

Comment: @kpeteL In other words, the thing that actually kicks off the DMA transfer is a BAR or PCI config write. Accessing the DMA buffer based only on the IOMMU-space addresses you get is another problem entirely, of course. You may need to look into how your virtual IOPCIDevice will interact with VT-d (see vtd.c in the IOPCIDevice source bundle). Unless the device you're simulating is extremely simple, this is whole thing is going to be a huge undertaking. Are you sure there's not a better way to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm using this approach to workaround some Apple's undisclosed source code. Or well, with the another method, there are walls to properly simulate a hostusbdevice. The memory trap isn't problem for me anymore, because I can filter my driver calls, and workout when to check the memory buffer.

Comment: hey @pmdj I now successfully made a virtual PCI device that maps the memory to userspace, but I'm having trouble making virtual interrupts. Or actually the drivers that attach to my device can't even add IOFilterInterruptEventSources. It fails when IOService::getInterruptType gets called. To fix this I assume I could just attach my own dummy IOInterruptController class to my device parent's branch. Then do you know any methods to fake an interrupt? Could I just use some dummy interrupt vectors e.g. 0x80?  Or what do you think?

Comment: @kpeteL re interrupts: drivers will be doing something similar to the sample code in the “Enabling MSI” section here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/HardwareDrivers/Conceptual/ThunderboltDevGuide/Basics02/Basics02.html - index 0 is typically the pin-based (numbered, shared) interrupt line. Indices 1..N are the MSI vectors. So at the driver level the PCI MSI vector numbers are already abstracted. You’ll need to wire things up such that the getInterruptType etc. methods on your class behave how IOInterruptEventSource/IOFilterInterruptEventSource expect.

Comment: @kpeteL Note that implementations of virtual USB host controllers for macOS are available commercially, mostly intended for USB-over-IP/ethernet solutions. The IOPCIDevice route sounds unnecessarily painful and indirect, but I obviously have no idea what you’re ultimately trying to do.

Comment: Hey @pmdj, I'm now trying to use redirect() method to hang the child write access to my memory, but I'm only able to block access of userclient. Basically now I get a hint when write is completed, but in order to synchronize or prevent concurrent writes I would like to block memory access of child driver. OR would it be possible to block child's thread? I can get the child by getClientEntry but I don't know if I could pause that thread somehow?

Comment: The already existing commercial implementations have compatibility issues

Comment: @kpeteL I don't know what happens if you `redirect()` a `kernel_task` mapping of a memory range, having never tried it. Pausing a thread in kernel context is a good way to lock up the system if that thread is on some critical path. As I mentioned in my answer, I suggest digging into the xnu kernel's virtual memory subsystem source code, if this really is the path you intend to take. Or at least that's where I'd look if I was attempting this. Fault handlers might be what you're looking for. Be aware that those run in interrupt context.

Comment: Hey @pmdj, got my virtual EHCI controller working. Now the problem is trying to access transfer buffers which are generated as IOBufferMemoryDescriptor, then using dmaCommand->gen32IOVMSegments(...&segments...) and the information of this buffer is passed to me by Apple's driver is segments.fIOVMAddr. Do you know if this could be reversed to point the original IOMemoryDescriptor, so I can read the buffer?

Comment: @kpeteL Have you established whether the addresses you are being passed are true physical addresses (CPU address space)? You need to make sure you're not ending up with addresses translated for the IOMMU (IO address space). If you have true physical addresses, you should be able to wrap them in a new IOMemoryDescriptor and read/write them via that. (Also note that asking a series of questions in comments isn't ideal; when you have a new question, you should post it as a new question.)